# i have written a programm in tkinter and sqlite3 but i am unable to update a specific column database using my primary key

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

```
def update():
    z = cname.get()

    print(z)
    j = ver.get()
    print(j)
    c.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS case_d(name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,crime TEXT,location TEXT,dt_of_arrest TEXT,officer TEXT,judge TEXT,defendant TEXT,prosecution TEXT,evidence TEXT,verdict TEXT)"
    )
    c.execute("UPDATE case_d SET verdict=? WHERE  name=?", (j, z))
    conn.commit()
    mb.showinfo(title="case ID", message="UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY")


r5 = Button(
    root, width=10, text="UPDATE", bd=5, relief="raised", bg="coral", command=update
).place(x=460, y=500)
```

in my above program I am getting my print statement work properly, but my database is not getting updated.

Comment: What is `c`? What is `conn`? You should probably be creating the table only at the start of your program, not on every `update`...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Are you sure there is a record with the specified name already in the database?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.